# Can't set headers after they are sent on repetitive hits

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node with express 4.x

My app.js code includes

```
// add generic library to global space
global._generic = generic;
connection.connect(function(err, db) {
if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
} else {

    connection.query('USE hakka');

    var attachDB = function(req, res, next) {
        req.db = connection;
        console.log("Attached DB to req variable. Now moving for next middleware...\n");
        next();
    };

    var requireLogin = function(req, res, next) {
        common.checkIdandToken(req, res, next);
    }

    var beforeRender = function(req, res, next) {
        _generic.res = res;
        baseController.beforeRender(req, res, next);
    }


    app.post('/api/v1/user', attachDB, beforeRender, function(req, res, next) {
        user.register(req, res, next);
    });

    app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '...\n');
    });
}
});
```

And for error in my model file my code is:

```
if (err) {
    _generic.res.status(err.errno).send({
        success: false,
        message: err.message
    });
}
```

It works fine most of the times. But when I make **repetitive hits very fast** then it gives me

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

PS:

Register method:

```
register: function(req, res, next) {

    var self = this;
    UserModel.setDB(req.db);

    console.log(req.body);
    UserModel.register(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
            res.status(200).send(self.createResponse({
                        token: token,
                        userid: sessionData.user_id
                    }, {
                        success: true,
                        message: "User has been registerd successfully"
                    }));
                    console.log("User has been registerd successfully...\n");
        } else {
            res.status(499).send(self.createResponse({}, {
                success: false,
                message: "User can not be registered"
            }));
            console.log("User can not be registered...\n");
        }
    });
}
```

UserModel.register:

```
register: function(data, callback) {
            var self = this;
            var userid = SOMERANDOMID;
            var post = {
                id: userid,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                phone: data.phone,
                user_status_id: 1
            };

            var query = self.db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post,
                    function(err, result, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            _generic.res.status(err.errno).send(
                                    self.createResponse({}, {
                                        success: false,
                                        message: err.message
                                    }));
                            console.log(err.message);
                            return false;
                        }

                        callback(err, result);
                    });
        }
```

**Phone number is UNIQUE in Database**

When using same phone number the response produced is:

```
{
  "status": {
    "success": false,
    "message": "ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '9898989898' for key 'Phone'"
    }
}
```

When I hit it again with same credentials I got the same response. But when I do repetitive hits very fast I got

ERROR: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Can you post the `user.register` method? Generally when sending the result use `return`: `return res.send()`, this way the execution of the function will stop